# Changing which DependencyProperty I bind to at run time

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm using WPF and have a data class which I bind to a control's DependencyProperties. I need to change the binding at run time under the control of a user. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
myControl.SetBinding(UserControl.GetDependencyProperty("HeightProperty")
    , myBinding);
```

Of course GetDependencyProperty taking a string doesn't work, I've got around this by creating my own static class

```
        public static DependencyProperty GetDP(string Name)
        {
            switch (Name)
            {
                case "Height": return UserControl.HeightProperty;
                case "Width": return UserControl.WidthProperty;
....
            }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't described how the user changes the target dependency property. Can you just store the `DependencyProperty`s themselves rather than `string`s? That way you don't have to do any conversion at all. Pseudo-code:

```
//just an array of all allowable properties
public DependencyProperty[] AllowedProperties { get; }

//the property the user has chosen
public DependencyProperty ChosenProperty { get; set; }

//called whenever ChosenProperty changes
private void OnChosenPropertyChanged()
{
    //redo binding here, using ChosenProperty as the target
}
```

**Edit after comments**: You can use DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName to get a DependencyProperty from its name, assuming you know the type of the owner:

```
var descriptor = DepedencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName(nameFromExcel, typeof(YourUserControl), typeof(YourUserControl));
var dependencyProperty = descriptor.DependencyProperty;
```

Comment: The user for various reasons will be driving this from Excel, hence needing to convert a string, the contents of an Excel cell to a DP. I like your AllowedProperties idea, but will still have the issue with ChosenProperty.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was after - cheers. BTW Your resizer code helped me out of a hole a while back - thanks again